# How to use proxy for specific url in Scrapy spider?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scrapy

I want to use proxy for only few specific domain. I check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47156149/unable-to-use-proxies-in-scrapy-project), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34230197/5381204) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710483/scrapy-and-proxies). If I understand correctly setting proxy using middleware will set the proxy for all requests.

How can I set proxy for specific url before the spider request is sent?

Currently my spider is working fine with following implementation:

`CoreSpider.py`

```
class CoreSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "final"
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_urls = self.read_url()
        self.rules = (
            Rule(
                LinkExtractor(
                    unique=True,
                ),
                callback='parse',
                follow=True
            ),
        )


    def read_url(self):
        urlList = []
        for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join("/root/Public/company_profiler/seed_list", '*.list')):
            with open(filename, "r") as f:
                for line in f.readlines():
                    url = re.sub('\n', '', line)
                    if "http" not in url:
                        url = "http://" + url
                    # print(url)
                    urlList.append(url)

        return urlList

    def parse(self, response):
        print("URL is: ", response.url)
        print("User agent is : ", response.request.headers['User-Agent'])
        filename = '/root/Public/company_profiler/crawled_page/%s.html' % response.url
        article = Extractor(extractor='LargestContentExtractor', html=response.body).getText()
        print("Article is :", article)
        if len(article.split("\n")) < 5:
            print("Skipping to next url : ", article.split("\n"))
        else:
            print("Continue parsing: ", article.split("\n"))
            ContentHandler_copy.ContentHandler_copy.start(article, response.url)
```

and `settings.py`

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'random_useragent.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 320
}
```

I am running spider by calling it via script `RunSpider.py`

`RunSpider.py`

```
from CoreSpider import CoreSpider
from scrapy.crawler import  CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings

process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
process.crawl(CoreSpider)
process.start()
```

**Update:**
`CoreSpider.py`

```
class CoreSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "final"
    def __init__(self):
        self.start_urls = self.read_url()
        self.rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True), callback='parse', follow=True, process_request='process_request'),
        )

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        print("Request is : ", request) ### Not printing anything
        if 'xxx' in request.url:  # <-- set proxy for this URL?
            meta = request.get('meta', {})
            meta.update({'proxy': 'https://159.8.18.178:8080'})
            return request.replace(meta=meta)
        return request
        .......
```

I also tried setting proxy like this in `process_request` method, but failed.

```
request.meta['proxy'] = "https://159.8.18.178:8080"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use proxy per request, specify `proxy` attribute of `Request`'s `meta` as per [documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-meta-special-keys). In case of `CrawlSpider`, you'll want to supply `process_request` argument to the [`Rule`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Rule). In that method, apply the above (i.e. setting `meta['proxy']`) selectively based on the request URL and return modified request with `meta` filled.

**EDIT:**
Replace the rule definition

```
self.rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True), callback='parse', follow=True),
)
```

with

```
self.rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True), callback='parse', follow=True, process_request='process_request'),
)
```

and define new method `process_request` in your `CoreSpider` class:

```
def process_request(self, request):
    if 'xxx' in request.url:  # <-- set proxy for this URL?
        meta = request.get('meta', {})
        meta.update({'proxy': 'your_proxy'})
        return request.replace(meta=meta)
    return request
```

**EDIT2:**
I think the problem might be caused by having `start_urls` and `rules` definition buried in the constructor:

```
...
def __init__(self):
    self.start_urls = self.read_url()
    self.rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True), callback='parse', follow=True, process_request='process_request'),
    )
...
```

The correct way is to have these attributes as *class* attributes, i.e.

```
class CoreSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "final"
    start_urls = self.read_url()
    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(unique=True), callback='parse', follow=True, process_request='process_request'),
    )
```

As for `start_urls`, in cases where you need something more complicated (e.g. reading URLs from external file), it might be better and more readable to define [`start_requests`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) to yield the `Request`s.

Comment: I didn't get you. How do I supply `process_request` argument to Rule? Could you please give example? I tried `class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        print("Here in proxy middleware.")
        request.meta['proxy'] = "proxy:port"` in `middlewares.py`. But it is not working.

Comment: It is not working. I tried printing the request in `process_request` method before checking condition, but it is not even printing anything. Perhaps `process_request` is not getting called for each url.

Comment: Could you edit the question and post update source code so I can check?

Comment: My bad! `process_request` was overridden for dynamic user-agent for every request. I made the suggested changes there and boom! now it is working.

Answer (score 1):

a standalone method. No middleware.

```
urls = [url, url, ..., url]
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['test.com']
    # start_urls = urls  # invalid, override by start_requests

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in urls:
            # handle each individual url with or without proxy
            # if url in ['no1.com', 'no2.com', 'no3.com']:
            if url == 'www.no_proxy.com':
                meta_proxy = '' # do not use proxy for this url
            else:
                meta_proxy = "http://127.0.0.1:8888"
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, meta={'proxy': meta_proxy})

    def parse(self, response):
        title = response.xpath('.//title/text()').extract_first()
        yield {'title': title}
```

usage:

```
$scrapy runspider test.py -o test.json -s CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN=100 -s CONCURRENT_REQUESTS=100
```

**Disclaimer:**

I don't know if it will slow down crawling speed or not, since it is iterating urls one by one. I do not have tons of testing sites for the moment. Hope someone who use this code will leave a comment to see what they got.

Answer (score 0):

I give you an example for using proxy with specific url

```
link = 'https://www.example.com/'
request = Request(link, callback=self.parse_url)
request.meta['proxy'] = "http://PROXYIP:PROXYPORT"
yield request
```

Comment: Where to set proxy like this in my implementation. Please have a look at question.

Comment: @OmPrakash check this one and let me know if it helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46567024/how-to-use-proxy-list-with-password-in-scrapy